# Can't calculate width of elements

Tags: javascript, html

I try to get width of DOM objects:

```
    function resizeArea(){
      var width = 0;
      area.children().each(function(i){
          alert(this.offsetWidth);
          width += this.offsetWidth;
      });
      area.css('width', width);
    }
```

In get results:

1. Chrome: 800
2. Opera: 708
3. FF: 783
4. IE: 714

But if see it in firebug, dragonfly and other debuggers i see correct 908px.
I don't know where porblem. I run this fun after domloaded.

Here is HTML and css of block:

```
<div class="scroll_area" id="scroll">
   <div class="area" id="area">
      <div class="category">
      [..]
      </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 <style>
    #scroll {
        position:realtive; width: 800px, heght: 400px;
   }
   #area {
        position:absolute; left: 0; top: 0;
   }
   #area .category, #area .category .text, #area .category .image{
       width: 200px
   }
 </style>
```

And that interesting. This function later work correctly, only at first run, for first calculating.

Comment: Since you're using jQuery, why not use `this.width()`?

Comment: @KennyTM
Same result. It get for me ideas that problem may be in html and css loading. But i don't know where is problem...
And if problem in loading css, result must be same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this to work (with jQuery):
**Please let me know if I misunderstood the question**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <style type="text/css">
    #scroll {
        position:realtive; width: 800px, heght: 400px;
   }
   #area {
        position:absolute; left: 0; top: 0;
   }
   #area div.category {
       width: 200px;
       display: block;
   }
 </style>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript" language="Javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function resizeArea(){
      var width = 0;
      jQuery("#area").children().each(function(i){
          alert(this.offsetWidth);
          width += this.offsetWidth;
      });
      jQuery("#area").css('width', width);
    }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="scroll_area" id="scroll">
   <div class="area" id="area">
      <div class="category">
      [..]FIRST ALERT
      </div>
      <div class="category">
      [..]SECOND ALERT
      </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">resizeArea();</script>

 <br /><br /><br /><a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="resizeArea()">Fun Function Again</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I test in my page, and bind resizeArea() to button, and it work correctly, but when i call resizeArea() in document.ready() it's not work( I don't know what cant load before dom:loaded..